# Why are the items not being created?

Tags: php

I'm blind, I can't see the error, where is it?

The script enters all IFs at least 1 time.

Before:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dealTag = $xml->createElement('DEAL');
```

```
<?php

if (!empty($dealContacts)) {
    echo '0IF' . '<br>';
    foreach ($rieltorsData as $rdContactId => $rdData) {
        echo '1IF' . '<br>';
        if ($rdContactId == $dealContacts) {
            echo '2IF' . '<br>';
            foreach ($rdData as $rdKey => $rdValue) {
                echo '3IF' . '<br>';
                if (is_array($rdValue)) {
                    echo '4IF' . '<br>';
                    foreach ($rdValue as $rvValue) {
                        echo '5IF' . '<br>';
                        $rieltyTag = $xml->createElement('Rielty');
                        $childTag = $xml->createElement('BCH', 'WORK');
                        $rieltyTag->appendChild($childTag);
                        $dealTag->appendChild($rieltyTag);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '6IF' . '<br>';
                    $rieltyTag = $xml->createElement('Rielty');
                    $childTag = $xml->createElement('BCH', 'WORK');
                    $rieltyTag->appendChild($childTag);
                    $dealTag->appendChild($rieltyTag);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is `appendChild` on `$dealTag` everything is OK there. `Rielty` is not created.
Tried it differently and nothing helped!

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEAL>
</DEAL>
```

Expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEAL>
  <Rielty>
    <BCH>WORK</BCH>
  </Rielty>
</DEAL>
```

UPD. I can't imitate error.
Here's comments:

```
if (!empty($dealContacts)) {
      foreach ($rieltorsData as $rdContactId => $rdData) {
        echo '0IF' . '<br>'; // THIS LINE WORKED!
        $testTag3 = $xml->createElement('TEST2', 'TEST2'); // THIS LINE WORKED!
        $dealTag->appendChild($testTag3); // THIS LINE WORKED!
        // <TEST2>TEST2</TEST2> CREATED!
        if ($rdContactId == $dealContacts) {
          echo '1IF' . '<br>'; // THIS LINE WORKED! ECHO WORKED! IF REACHED! BUT...
          $testTag3 = $xml->createElement('TEST3', 'TEST3'); // THIS LINE NOT WORKED!
          $dealTag->appendChild($testTag3); // THIS LINE NOT WORKED!
          // ! <TEST2>TEST2</TEST2> NOT CREATED!
          // ! WHYYYYYYYY?
```

UPD. I just `appendChild` before `createElement` on `$dealTag` and now it's work!

```
$dealTag = $xml->createElement('DEAL');
$dealsTag->appendChild($dealTag);
```

Comment: Give definitions for `$dealTag` and `$xml`; In generell you should provide an [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Whats the actual issue here? It doesnt show anything or what? How do you echo the result? How do you verify its *"not being created"*?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Well there is information lacking. I also dont see you appending `$rieltyTag` anywhere. [For me it works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c08bc0566f36afaede726ff08f0cc770c3040fc4). Go ahead and create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i update descripion, check please.

Comment: **This is my last comment! Any comments provided by you after this will be ignored by me.** [For me it still works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c452e9944ff6d0fa25656397e230ebcd93bc8397). I dont really know what youre doing wrong, because you dont want to [provide an reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And if you cant provide an example then we cant help you, sorry.

Comment: I write that i can't.